# How to rebuild a DLL dynamically within UWP and C#?

Tags: c#, batch-file, uwp, process, msbuild

I want to allow the user to update, rebuild and run an internal app DLL.

But...I find UWP doesn't support Microsoft.Build or System.Diagnostics.Process.

Is it possible to run VSDevCmd.bat dynamically? Is there ANY way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

That isn't possible in a UWP app's security model.